# How to expose a member objects interface in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

C++ : I have a basic object (object A) that contains a member object (object B). The member object interface (object B) needs to be fully exposed through the pointer to object A. What's the best way to do this? I could place the object as a public member but this feels like a hack. I could write wrappers for all B's interface in A but this feels ugly. I could merge the objects but I am doing class serialization to XML so having distinct classes is cleaner. I thought about friend classing but I don't think that applies to this situation.

What is the standard way to resolve this type of issue?

Comment: Maybe a getter function that returns the pointer to object B?

Comment: B needs to be exposed, but can the operations on it be const-qualified?

Comment: No, in this case it isn't const. It needs to be mutable.

Comment: Are you sure you have a "A contains B" relationship and not a "B is a kind of A"?

Answer (score 1):

Let `B` implement an interface `IB`. `A` manages an instance of `B` internally and has a getter `getB` that returns the `IB` interface of the private `B` instance. If you want to protect the `B` instance, you can make the `IB` methods `const` and also hide the destructor (by making it private in `IB`).

```
class IB {
private:
    ~IB();
public:
    virtual void method1() = 0;
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class B : public IB {
public:
    virtual void method1() {};
    virtual void method2() {};

    void destruct() { delete this; }
};

class A {
private:
    B myB;
public:
    IB *getB() { return &myB; }
};
```

(This is just to give an idea. It's been 3+ years since I last touched C++. I could have made some blatant errors.)

Answer (score 0):

I reject the notion that doing this at all is a good idea, but I would make it a public member.  If you don't like that you can have a getB() method.  If possible, I would make it return a const reference instead of a normal reference.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the -> operator in A and in the implementation return the pointer variable of type B.
But as you know you will not be able to access A's members through A's pointer and ->. Also it has the risk of causing confusion who ever read the code.
I meant something like this.

```
struct A
{
  B *p;
  B * operator -> ()
  {
    return p;
  }
};
```